# How to connect db from local machine that can only be connected from windows remote desktop

Tags: rdp, ssh-tunnel, http-tunneling, localtunnel

The question says it all. But to elaborate.

I have a oracle db running at some remote host. ip: 10.0.0.121 port: 1521
It can be accessed when I connect to a windows remote desktop machine.
Now how can I connect to this remote db from my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that localtunnel is similar to [telebit](https://telebit.cloud/) in that you get an encrypted https connection, not a plain tcp connection (which is good).

If I understand correctly, you'll want to use localtunnel (or telebit or perhaps even ngrok) on the windows machine to expose its database connection to the outside world. You'll want to use https (and absolutely not tcp or http which would leak database passwords and all your data) to create the tunnel.

Then you'll need to run something like [sclient](https://telebit.cloud/sclient/) (or stunnel) on the computer that's doing the connecting to "unwrap" the https connection back to plain tcp. It might look like this:

```
sclient example.localtunnel.me:443 localhost:1521
```

In your database client or application you would then use `localhost:1521` in your database connection string (not the https address).

This gives you the security of an encrypted connection and the convenience of exposing ports out to the world, all without adding any complexity to your application or client - you just run it as normal, connecting to localhost.

Comment if you need any additional clarification.